# How to inject objects into groovy servlet?

Tags: servlets, groovy, inject

First, no grails and no spring.

I just use groovy servlet (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/servlet/GroovyServlet.html)

if I have a servlet named user_action.groovy, and I have UserDao.groovy, UserService.groovy, how can I inject services or daos into servlet please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a servlet container that supports JNDI, such as Tomcat, you could potentially configure your UserDao class as a JNDI resource, and then access it via the JNDI directory lookup. That would provide a level of indirection, but relies on external configuration.

Another option is to include a DI framework such as Tiger or Guice if you're not interested in Spring based DI.

But injection by nature requires some form of Dependency Injection framework to support it. Otherwise you just go:

```
def dao = new UserDao()
```